# Does $e^{j2\pi kt} = (e^{j2\pi k})^t$?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm working on an electrical engineering problem set. My confusion is not with the concepts of the topics I'm covering, rather with a bit of mathematics.

Does:

$$e^{j2\pi kt} = (e^{j2\pi k})^t, k \in \mathbb{Z}, |k| \leq 3, t \in \mathbb{R}, j = \sqrt{-1}$$

For context (off topic, but you might see the motivation for my question), the problem is asking me to find a function $f(t)$ with some period $T$ that has been filtered such that only the Fourier Coefficients (of the function) $c_k = 0, |k| > 3 $. If the above statement is true, I'd say $e^{j2\pi kt} = (e^{j2\pi k})^t = 1^t = 1$, which simplifies my calculations.

Wolfram tells me it's only true for $t=0$ but I'm clearly missing something fundamental here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $t$ is not an integer, you will be incorrect. For example, let $t = \frac{1}{2k}$. Then $e^{j2\pi kt} = e^{j\pi} = -1$ not $1$.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is NO.

For example, let $k=1$ and $t=1/2$, then
$$ e^{j 2 \pi k t} = e^{j \pi} = -1 \tag{1} $$
and
$$ (e^{j 2 \pi k})^t = 1^{1/2} = 1. \tag{2}$$

Clearly, (1) $\neq$ (2).

Comment: Lol. I can't believe I didn't think of that.  Thank you!

Comment: Important to note here that we actually have $1^{1/2} = \{1,-1\}$. The solution hasn't disappeared... We just got another solution.